# If every element of a lattice includes an atom, does it follow that the lattice is atomistic?

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $L$ be a lattice with no zero element and define '$x$ is an atom' as '$\neg\exists y \, y<x$'. Suppose that $\forall x\exists y (y\text{ is an atom and }y<x)$.

Does it follow that every element in $L$ is a join of atoms?

Comment: The property cannot hold for a lattice with a bottom element, because a bottom element cannot cover any atom. What is an "atom" to you in a lattice without bottom?

Comment: Well, I think I can see what you *wanted* to ask; the answer to the question you wanted to ask is "No". The counterexample has 3 elements.

Comment: Apologies. I'm new to lattice theory. I'm trying to use it to answer a question in mereology and my translation didn't quite pan out. I meant to stipulate that the lattice had no zero element. To clarify: given the stipulation that there is no zero, x is an atom iff there is no y such that y<x. @bof The finite models are trivially atomistic, so I'm most interested in infinite chains.

Comment: I edited the original question in response to the comments. Maybe it's trivial, but I assure you that this is the question I intended to ask :)

Comment: If a lattice has an "atom" as you define it (i.e. a minimal element) then the "atom" is unique and is the zero element of the lattice. Maybe you should define what you mean by "lattice".

Answer (score 1):

What about the lattice $L$ of subsets of $\mathbb R$ generated by all open intervals and all subsets of rational numbers?

A general element of $L$ is of the form $U \cup A$ where $U \subset \mathbb R$ is open and $A \subset \mathbb Q\subset \mathbb R$ is arbitrary.

That lattice has arbitrary joins. But the only atoms are $\{q\}$ for $q \in \mathbb Q$. For example $(0,1)$ is not a join of atoms.